# PostgreSQL DSN Connection string in C#

Tags: c#, dsn

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL database to C# application. For that I have created ODBC data source, now I need the connection string to include in C#.

**Question**: How to write DSN connection string for PostgreSQL in C#?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 // PostgeSQL-style connection string
   string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" + 
                    "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
                    tbHost.Text, tbPort.Text, tbUser.Text, 
                    tbPass.Text, tbDataBaseName.Text );
                // Making connection with Npgsql provider
   NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
   conn.Open();
   // quite complex sql statement
   string sql = "SELECT * FROM simple_table";
   // data adapter making request from our connection
   NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
```

More details here  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr

Answer (score 0):

**this worked for me**

```
 "DefaultConnection": "User ID=postgres;Password=aamir7882;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=kingsurplus;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;
```

get server details and database details from pgAdmin 4